# how to paraphrase "the dusky, golden softness"

Tags: meaning-in-context

The following quote is from "SONS AND LOVERS" by D.H.LAWRENCE:

She was a puritan, like her father, high-minded, and really stern.  Therefore, **the dusky, golden** **softness of** this man's sensuous flame of life, that flowed off his flesh like the flame from a candle, not baffled and gripped into incandescence by thought and spirit as her life was, seemed to her something wonderful, beyond her.

One of the problems we non-native speakers often encounter when reading English classical literature is paraphrasing abstract nouns, like "**the dusky, golden softness** of..." in the above quote.
Would you please help me paraphrase it in plain expressions?

Answer (score 1):

The *Dusky, golden softness of this man's sensuous flame of life* is a metaphor that is hard for me, a native speaker, to understand.  D.H. acknowledges this by pairing the dense metaphor with an easier to understand simile.  We learn that the DGS flows off his flesh **like the flame from a candle**.  And there you have it explained - the dusky, golden softness is like the flame from a candle.  Think of a candle's dim, gentle light giving off its little bit of heat. This man's sensuality flowed from him like the light from a candle.  It wasn't overpowering. It wasn't conspicuous or demanding.  It was dusky, golden, softness.

Roughly speaking of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Your explanation is helpfuo.